# How to add website "/" root page to filesMatch list?

Tags: .htaccess

Tried searching here, but seems that there is no answer for my particular case.

So, i use this inside my .htaccess file to allow access only to several files inside my website:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html

DirectoryIndex index.html
Order Allow,Deny
<filesMatch "(index\.html|somefile\.txt|somefile2\.txt)">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

So i want to let user open only homepage, that is index.html, and couple of txt files, you can see from the code block. If user opens "https://example.com/index.html" it works perfect, but if user tries to open "https://example.com/" he sees 403 error. How can i add "/" to allowed pages?

I tried to add smth like:

```
<filesMatch "(index\.html|/|somefile\.txt|somefile2\.txt)">
```

but no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the "empty file" you need to allow, not `/` (which is effectively the "directory", not the file). But you also need to surround the regex in *anchors* (start and end-of-string), otherwise you will successfully "match" every file. (Without the anchors on your original regex you are permitting access to `abcsomefile\.txtxyz` etc. which may or may not be an issue.)

So, from your example you could just make the pattern optional (providing you also include anchors around the regex). For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(index\.html|somefile\.txt|somefile2\.txt)?$">
```

Alternatively, have an *empty* element in your regex alternation (not `/`). For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(|index\.html|somefile\.txt|somefile2\.txt)$">
```

Although consider redirecting `/index.html` to `/` to avoid canonicalisation (duplicate content) issues.

Note that `Order` and `Allow` are Apache 2.2 directives. If you are using Apache 2.4 then these are formerly deprecated and you should be using the equivalent `Require` directives instead.

Comment: Hi MrWhite, thanks for your reply. I already tried this variant: `<FilesMatch "(|index\.html|somefile\.txt|somefile2\.txt)">` and it allows user open every file inside website, so, is not what i need. Also i have just tried variant with "?" - and in this case it also allows to show every file...

Comment: @AndrewPoroshenko Ah, sorry, you also need to surround the regex in start-of-string and end-of-string anchors (ie. `^` and `$` respectively), otherwise it will indeed "match" everything. (Without the anchors on your original regex you are potentially matching too much as well.) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi again, MrWhite, the updated version works perfect! Now 100% what i need, many thanks. I will mark now this answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any way to do this with `FilesMatch`. How about a solution using mod_rewrite instead?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(|index\.html|somefile\.txt|somefile2\.txt)$
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

The RewriteCond checks that the requested URI was *not* one of those you wanted to allow, and if that condition is fulfilled, then the following rule will make it give a 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: Alternatively, the non-negated regular expression could also be used with an `<If>`, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples - then you could keep using `Allow from all` inside, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Small point, but you don't need the empty element in the _CondPattern_ alternation, since your `RewriteRule` _pattern_ only matches non-empty URL-paths. (Although the `RewriteCond` directive is not required at all here and the check should really be performed in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ instead.)

Comment: Hi Cbroe and thanks for your answer. It seems that your solution is also good, but for some reason is not working at my server, cause (maybe) mod_rewrite is not active of for other reason...but thanks a lot for your reply!